# return array with elements that can be repeated only N times

Tags: c#

I am trying to practice some c# questions and I came across a question where given an integer of array, return the array with elements that can be repeated only N times. So, if I have {1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3} and my N=2, my result should be {1,2,3,4,1,2,3}. I tried something but I get the result as {2,3,4,1,1,2,3}.I don't want the first repeated element be removed. 
This is what I have tried :

```
        int[] intArray = {3,2,3,1,3};          
        int N = 2;
        var list = new List<int>(intArray);
        var newList = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {

            int occur = 1;
            for (int j = i+1; j < list.Count; j++)
            {
                if (occur < N && list[i] == list[j])
                {
                    occur++;
                    newList.Add(list[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (list[i] == list[j] )
                        list.Remove(list[j]);
                }
            }

        }
        foreach (var l in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l);
        }



    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a dictionary to keep track of how many times each integer has been encountered:

```
int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
int N = 2;
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, int>();
LIst<int> list = new List<int>();

foreach (int num in intArray)
{
    if (!lookup.ContainsKey(num))
    {
        lookup[num] = 1;
        list.Add(num);
    }
    else if (lookup[num]++ < N)
    {
        list.Add(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not going to ask how in the  world you did this in less than 5 mins but this works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `Dictionary<T, int>` to count appearances:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> RepeatOnly<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int times) {
  Dictionary<T, int> counts = new Dictionary<T, int>();

  foreach (var item in source) {
    int count;

    if (counts.TryGetValue(item, out count))
      counts[item] = ++count;
    else 
      counts.Add(item, count = 1);

    if (count <= times)
      yield return item;
  }
}
```

....

```
int[] source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3 };

int[] result = RepeatOnly(source, 2).ToArray(); 

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```